# ffmpeg sorting order issue while creating video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am able to successfully able to convert images to video using below command where all photos of
out directory is used.

```
$command1 = "ffmpeg -r 1/1 -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i 'out/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf 'pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2' out/1.mp4";
exec($command1);
```

However the photos are getting picked randomly and I want to pick them using sort order example.

```
Pic1.jpg, Pic2.jpg, Pic2.jpg ......
```

Please suggest what to do here?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a prefix `start_number` instead of `-pattern_type glob`.

As explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/666994/469489), the `*` glob does not work as expected.

If your images are in these order:

> *Pic1.jpg, Pic2.jpg, Pic3.jpg* and so on...

Use  `-start_number` instead, the updated `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/1 -framerate 25 -start_number 1 -i 'out/Pic%d.jpg' -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf 'pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2' out/1.mp4
```